# Extending generic typing for the nested Object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to dynamically set a type for the record of the interfaces.

```
interface ChildInput<V> = {value: V};
```

Now, I would like to have a record of different `ChildInput<V>`s.
So, `ParentInput` would look like something like this:

```
interface ParentInput<Keys extends string, T> /*this is the point of the question*/ = {
  [index: Keys]: ChildInput<?> /*this is the point of the question*/
}
```

for example:

```
const parentInput =  {
  foo: {value: 2},
  bar: {value: 'bar'},
  foobar: {value: true},
  .
  .
  .
}
```

expected result for the `parentInput` should be something like this:

```
interface ParentInput {
  foo: ChildInput<number>,
  bar: ChildInput<string>,
  foobar: ChildInput<boolean>,
}
```

Number of keys having `ChildInput` type in `parentInput` variable is not known. Also the type of the value.
I want to find a way, given the variable, dynamically types the `parentInput` with right types for the `ChildInput`.

The question for me is hard to formulate and explain. Please write for more clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. It seems like you are trying to generate a dynamic type from a runtime value which doesn't really make sense as you can't create types out of runtime values.

Comment: From what I understand, the best you can do is to do `interface ChildInput = { value: unknown }` as you don't know what the value type is beforehand. Then you would need to use runtime checks to figure out the types later (e.g. `typeof x === "string"`)

Comment: it is possible to infer type of the keys and values of an object, in this example `parentInput`.

Comment: Inference is automatic, yes. Or if you want to turn it into a type you can do `type MyType = typeof parentInput`. But this type won't know anything about your `ChildInput` interface

Comment: I think you want some sort of mapped type, but I'm not understanding what is known and what is unknown.  Does the relationship between `foo` and `number` exist somewhere, or is that what we are trying to guess?

Answer (score 0):

The key problem here is that you need to map from the name/key to a type. The only way to do this is with a fully defined object type literal or interface. So we can provide a simpler interface as a generic input and then use a mapped type to translate this into the resultant shape.

```
interface ChildInput<T> {
    value: T
}

type ParentInput<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: ChildInput<T[K]>
}

type Example = ParentInput<{
    foo: number,
    bar: string,
    foobar: boolean
}>

// Example will be
// {
//   foo: ChildInput<number>,
//   bar: ChildInput<string>,
//   foobar: ChildInput<boolean>,
// }
```

This may only be useful is ChildInput is more complicated or you use this mapping in a lot of types so that it is saving more redundancy.